# Resize font if text doesnt fit into cell (XRTable)

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

How to resize cell content (font size) if it doesn't fit. I don't want word-wrap or change cell's size since the form has to fit on single page. The text might have various lengths. It might contain spaces but doesn't have to.

@edit

I've made a mistake. The control I meant is not a `XtraGrid` but `XRTable`.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Reading their documentation, couldnt really find anything usefull. I can probably calculate the text height and width by hand. However, I'm asking if there's some kind of way foreseen by devexpress itself.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using System Drawing somewhere? If so, try using this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and looping through font sizes to find the one that works best for your area?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Majkl Your solution might work, I didn't have time to check it yet, gonna update immediately when I do so.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look at the [Appearances](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114599) at first. There are multiple ways to [customize appearances of individual rows and cells](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758).

If these options are not helpful, you can manually draw cell content as you needed using the [Custom Drawing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114616) feature. For example, you can use the [GridView.CustomDrawCell](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic) event to check whether or not the cell's content is exceed the cell's bounds and update the font of this cell accordingly.

Related example: [How to: Custom Draw Cells Depending Upon Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3027)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font of the cell where the text flows as follows

```
private void gvView_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Column != null && e.Column.Name == bgcStav.Name)
      {
        float minFontSize = 6;
        string text = "teeeeeeeeeeeeeext";
        int minWidth = gvView.CalcColumnBestWidth(bgcStav);        
        SizeF s = e.Appearance.CalcTextSize(e.Graphics, text, minWidth);
        if (s.Width >= minWidth)
        {
          e.Appearance.Font = new Font(e.Appearance.Font.FontFamily, minFontSize);          
        }
      }
    }
```

but it is much better to trim the text if it overflows (you do not know how long the text can be), when you do not want to use wordwrap

```
 private void gvView_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Column != null && e.Column.Name == bgcStav.Name)
      {
        string text = e.DisplayText;
        string newText = "";
        int maxWidth = e.Bounds.Width - 20;
        SizeF textSize =e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, e.Appearance.Font);
        if (textSize.Width >= maxWidth)
        {
          string textPom = "";
          for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
          {
            textPom = text.Substring(0, i) + "...";
            textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(textPom, e.Appearance.Font);
            if (textSize.Width >= maxWidth)
            {
              newText = text.Substring(0, i - 1) + "...";
              break;
            }
          }
          e.DisplayText = newText;
        }           
      }
    }
```

Advantage of this solution is that the crop only what is displaied, but in the datatable text remains in its original form

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Your solution would work on `XtraGrid`, but I've made mistake in my question. Please see the update.